# Separating values based on duplicates in a row into new columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following example of dataframe:

```
  first         second       third
 ----------------------------------
  A             1            A1
  A             2            A2
  A             3            A2
  B             1            B1
  C             1            C1
  C             2            C2
```

Is there any way to split the second column and third column into new column based on the duplicated values/rows in the first column? Like this:

```
  first         second       second.2      second.3    third   third.2     third.3
  A             1            2             3           A1      A2          A2
  B             1            NA            NA          B1      NA          NA
  C             1            2             NA          C1      C2          NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `data.table::dcast` to convert to a wide format. The right side of `~` here is like the `names_from` argument to `pivot_wider`, and the `value.var` is like the `values_from` argument. So the columns will be [value.var name].rowid(first), where `rowid(first)` creates within-group row numbers where the group is determined by the value of `first`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

dcast(df, first ~ rowid(first), value.var = c('second', 'third'), sep = '.')

#    first second.1 second.2 second.3 third.1 third.2 third.3
# 1:     A        1        2        3      A1      A2      A2
# 2:     B        1       NA       NA      B1    <NA>    <NA>
# 3:     C        1        2       NA      C1      C2    <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is `pivot_wider`.  Here, the 'second' column is also a sequence column for each group of 'first', So, duplicate that column with `mutate` and then use `pivot_wider` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(rn = second) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from  = rn, values_from = c(second, third), names_sep = ".")
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#  first second.1 second.2 second.3 third.1 third.2 third.3
#  <chr>    <int>    <int>    <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#1 A            1        2        3 A1      A2      A2     
#2 B            1       NA       NA B1      <NA>    <NA>   
#3 C            1        2       NA C1      C2      <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(first = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C"), second = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), third = c("A1", "A2", "A2", "B1", "C1", 
"C2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: When using this code for a real dataframe, I get instead another structure, with collumns named A, B and C and values of each category under it. What am I doing wrong? Maybe what I wanted to say is that I must use the "first" collumn as a reference for categories

Comment: @GabrielG. I created the code based on th example you showed

Comment: @GabrielG.  As I mentioned in the post, the row number sequence 'rn' is based on the 'second' column.  If that is not the case, you may need `df1 %>% group_by(first) %>% mutate(rn = second) %>%...` and then the rest should work